# Persistent background Android service

Tags: android, android-service

This seems like a trivial question but I am having a hard time making this work.

I am making a instant messaging app, and I need a background service that runs all the time without taking account the state of the main app.

Right now I started it with `onBind` and `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`, and it spawns a worker thread to do networking-related work. The thing is that when I swipe away my app (close it) the service closes as well.

What should I do to keep my service running all the time, after my app closes?

Comment: you might add some broadcast receiver, and start your service always in this broadcast receiver.

Comment: I already added a broadcast receiver, but I am debugging it in Android Studio, so I have to install/uninstall it all the time.

Comment: have you solved this? how?